# PHPUnit CIUnit Issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, jenkins, phpunit

When I run a specific test suite,

```
phpunit --testsuite LibTests
```

I get my expected results (passing tests). However, when I run "phpunit", I get an error claiming:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function rss_feed_url() on a non-object in /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/Fanpilot_CT_3.0/workspace/tests/libs/VoltampMediaRSSFeedTest.php on line 20
```

where rss_feed_url() is a method of a class I loaded in setup().

Here is a snippet of my phpunit.xml file

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="LibTests">
      <directory suffix=".php">tests/libs</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was I was not reinitializing $this->CI to the proper controller. It was stale from the last test. In every setUp()m you need to be sure to initialize $this-CI, like this:

```
$this->CI = set_controller();
```

In my case, I have a custom MY_Controller (applications/core/My_Controller.php). Therefore, I can do this if I need to leverage my custom controller.

```
$this->CI = set_controller('MY_Controller');
```

As a side note, I finally figured it out by dumping both the get_class and the get_parent_class within the CIU_Loader method, _ci_load_class, and I noticed that these values depending on whether I ran it as a single test or as everything.

Answer (score 0):

It seems in phpunit that most class variables get unset between test methods.  If that's the issue (it sounds like it, with the non-object error).  I believe I solved this issue for myself by making those variables private and/or static.